# Array of SlimReaderWriter (SRW) Locks (using new operator)

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, locking

Maybe this sounds stupid, but I want to create a vector/array of SRWLocks dynamically during runtime.  The following code compiles both ways, but the array thing doesn’t work. Probably the question should be, can I create an SRWLock object using the new operator?

If this is not how it’s done, what’s the right way to create an array of SRWLock objects?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ppl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define NOT_WORKING

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


#ifdef NOT_WORKING

// The following doesn't work
       SRWLOCK *lock = new SRWLOCK[2];

       int a = 10;

       AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&lock[0]);
       cout<<"Exclusive Lock Acquired";
       a++;
       ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&lock[0]);


       // The following doesn't work either

       /*
       SRWLOCK *lock_n = new SRWLOCK;


       AcquireSRWLockExclusive(lock_n);
       cout<<"Exclusive Lock Acquired";
       a++;
       ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(lock_n);

       */

       #else
// This works
       SRWLOCK lock;

       int a = 10;
       AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&lock);
       cout<<"Exclusive Lock Acquired";
       a++;
       ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&lock);

#endif
       cout<<"Value of a:"<<a;
       cin.get();

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got it! One needs to use the InitializeSRWLock() function when lock objects are created dynamically. Somebody paste this answer, and help me close this question.

Answer (score 0):

User1577008's own answer:
Got it! One needs to use the InitializeSRWLock() function when lock objects are created dynamically. Somebody paste this answer, and help me close this question.